# SpringSource ToolSuite and Subclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

since I use SpringSource ToolSuite 2.7.1 and installed the latest Subclipse Plugin (1.6.x), this plugin ask's me every time I commit something into the repo for my password, regardless I've enabled the 'Save Password' checkbox. As I know, the Subclipse plugin doesn't store the credentials itself, instead use the authentication informations from the underlying SVN adapter so I try the following without any success:

1) delete ~/.subversion/auth

2) delete ~/.eclipse_keyring

After restarting STS the password dialog prompts again every time.

With Eclipse Indigo and the same Subclipse Plugin installed, this strange behavior doesn't happend, the passowrd is taken automatically as expected.
If I use svn from the command line, after I initially enter my passwords, it's used automatically and doesn't annoying me any longer.

Any sugggestions, why this doesn't work under SpringSource Toolsuite ?

Kind regards
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: the reason was, that the STS.app do not has access to the MacOS X KeyChain for the SVN password. So therefor it has to ask again and again. The used Eclipse.app was added as trusted app for accessing the stored svn password. Strangely, I can't add STS.app to the list of trusted apps for the SVS password entry, but thats [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441566/macos-x-keychain-cant-set-an-app-as-trustworthy) here. If I activate the 'access for every program' checkbox, STS.app is enable to read this password and don't ask any longer !

Comment: Hi, encountering the same issue and its driving me crazy. Can you elaborate on activating 'access for every program' and what SVS is? Unfamiliar with what OSX feature you're talking about there- thanks!

Comment: 'access for every program' mean an option for a given password from the keystore managed by KeyChainAccess.app under MacOS X. Start that tool under /Applications/Utilities, select your desired password (in my case the Subversion/SVN (not SVS, sorry) password, open the information by doubleclick and select the right tab named 'Access' or so ... my german MacOSX say 'Zugriff'. Here you can manage the list of trustworthy app or allow the access to this password for every programm. And I have to use that first option.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! ... but no change here. STS was always buggy, but lately, I find it far too unreliable to work with, on OSX at least, and its an incredible resource hog- 200% CPU on a quadcore 2.7 GHz machine with 4Gb RAM to build with maven? Really??? Think I'll file a bug about this- the password issue only kicked in yesterday when i upgraded to 2.7.22 :(

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This was driving me crazy. In the Keychain Access application, I could see that the STS app had been added a million times already. Apparently, OSX doesn't recognize it as the same application and keeps asking and adding it...

Comment: FWIW, same problem for me with Eclipse (Luna). Whenever I open Eclipse, Mac prompts me for allowing access to "equinox.secure.storage". I've hit "always" so many times ... it still continues prompting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with the subclipse plugin.  I tried it a few times some years ago and it didn't go well for me.  I then switched to subversive.  I have not experienced this problem with the subversive plugin, and so perhaps you could try switching and seeing if this will help you.

Comment: I've compared both plugin before and choose Subclipse due to the better rating, but maybe I'll give Subversive a chance... But as I wrote, I use Subclipse since a few months without any problems from within Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7. The nagging dialog comes up with STS 2.7.1 so I've to ask the Spring forum too!

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting or renaming the ~/.subversion folder.  There are also settings in the config and servers file that can prevent password storage.  You also do not mention what access method you are using ... for example passwords are not stored for svn+ssh://

It would also be relevant to know if you are using JavaHL or SVNKit.  JavaHL is native Subversion so passwords are cached in ~/.subversion/auth.  SVNKit caches passwords in the Eclipse keyring, but I believe it will read from the SVN password cache if it is already there -- or at least used to.

Finally, since it works with Eclipse but not STS (and there should be no reason why) maybe check permissions?  Is STS running as a different user for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

The settings for the secure storage are equal. But it seems, that these setting aren't used, the mentioned file doesn't exist. In the meantime I've installed the STS 2.7.2 update and a fresh Subclipse Plugin, but without success, the dialog popups again for every commit. After that, I create a new user, copy the whole STS 2.7.2 install dir including Maven, tc and the just installed Subclipsed plugin to a dir shared for all users. I have to fix the file permissions of the maven subdir due to lack of read permissions for the new user. I checked out a project from svn and modified it. After the initially question for username/password, this dialog don't popups any longer. It seems, that for this new user, things went fine. I switch back to the original user and start STS 2.7.2. from exactly the same place, the shared dir. But ... you predict it ... the dialog popups again and again and again .... It seems to be something wrong with any of my user settings, but which one ? I've delete ~/.subversion/auth and the whole ~/.subversion too. No way to avoid the constant question for the password for the given user. Mhm, strange, any further tips or suggestions ?