# MacOS X Keychain: Can't set an app as trustworthy

Tags: macos, keychain

I would like to add an app (STS.app, the SpringSource ToolSuite) to the list of trusted apps for a given password entry within my keychain. The list already contains some apps (svn, Eclipse.app) but I can't add the given STS.app. After I choose that file from the file dialog, the list remains unchanged. I can delete/add other apps, e.g. the mentioned Eclipse.app but not the STS.app. Both files have equal permissions, but STS.app contains the com.apple.quarantine extended attribute. I can manually remove this ext.attribute (why does it ever exists, and why it wasn't removed automatically after the first start after download them via Chrome ???) but the STS.app is still not able to set as trusted app in keychain after that. Any suggestion ?

Kind regards, Dominik

Comment: What is wrong with the standard process? Run STS.app, it asks for the key, the OS asks you, you say “always allow” and the OS writes that down. Does that work?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention the original problem I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331486/springsource-toolsuite-and-subclipse-plugin/). Short summary: STS.app asks everytime for the password and can't save it for later use.

Comment: Some problem, started today...

Answer (score 2):

After experiencing the same problem, I created the keychain item manually and that fixed it for me.

Go to your Mac keychain, click the '+' at the bottom, and then enter your SVN URL, friendly name and password.